# TypeScript Не работает Array<T>, выдает ошибку

Tags: typescript

```
var value;
var unit;
var list: Array<Student>;

function Acceptor()
{
    console.log("Acceptor")
    value = parseFloat((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("myValue")).value);
    unit = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("myUnit")).value;

    list.push(new Student(value, unit));
}
```

Функция вызывается кнопкой из html страницы.

```
 <div id="content">
        <input id="myValue" type="number">
        <input id="myUnit" type="text">
        <button id="button1" onclick="Acceptor()">Send Information</button>
    </div>
```

В браузере в консоли пишет "TypeError: list is undefined", с ссылкой на `list.push(new Student(value, unit));`.

Answer (score 1):

У вас переменная `list` только объявлена, но не инициализирована поэтому когда вы пытаетесь использовать метод `push()` получаете ошибку `TypeError: list is undefined`
Создать массив можно следующим образом:
`var list: Array<Student> = [];`